# Possible to include a command-line in a Node module without global install?

Tags: node.js, path, command-line-interface, npm

I have a small Node module that includes a command line script in the `bin` directory.

```
    "bin": {
        "generate": "./bin/generate.js"
    }
```

The `generate.js` script is properly executable.

This all works fine if I run `npm install -g`. But I'd prefer not to globally install and only have the command `generate` work from inside the module folder. If I run `npm install` from the module folder, it does correctly install all of the dependencies in a `node_modules` subdirectory. But then `generate` from the command like gives me "No such file or directory."

Thx.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I never install node modules using `-g`. My solution for your problem is to add this to my `$PATH`

```sh
# add this to ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc, or ~/.profile, etc
export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

Now, so long as your in the root of your module, you can access any binaries that have been installed as modules.

---

As an example, `less` is commonly installed with

```
npm install -g less
```

However, if you have your PATH modified as described above, you could something like this

```
cd my_node_module
npm install --save less
lessc less/style.less css/style.css
```

Without the PATH modification, you would've seen

```
command not found: lessc
```

---

If you don't feel like altering your PATH, you can access the binary directly

```
cd my_node_module
npm install --save lessc
./node_modules/.bin/lessc a.less a.css
```

---

Yay, no more `npm install -g ...`

Comment: Thank you, perfect response. I think you mean npm install less. (Lessc is name of cli)

Comment: An executable is created everytime whether it is globally or locally installed. In latter case, you just need to modify the PATH.